# How to put a custom shape of bars in syncfusion bar chart, flutter?

Tags: flutter, charts, syncfusion

I am using **syncfusion** bar charts in flutter. I want know know if there is a way to change the shape of the bars in this library or specifically how to change the library files so as to achieve this.

I tried to place the library folder inside the flutter project and then edit the files but it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have analyzed your requirement that you want to change the shapes of the bar series. We have support to render the bars with rounded corner using borderRadius property inside the bar series class. You can use below code snippet for rounded corner bars

```
BarSeries<ChartSampleData, String>(
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
)
```

[image]

We have extendable classes in our chart. you can extend the bar series class and customize the bar shape as per your requirement.
For your convenience, we attached the sample of the customized bar chart which can be found below.
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/262513/ze/main1804179932

[image]

If you want to edit the source file, you should add the dependency as your local path in which the syncfusion_flutter_charts package is present instead of referring the package from pub.dev.

```
dependencies:
  syncfusion_flutter_charts:
    path: D:/flutter_charts/syncfusion_flutter_charts
```

For more information on our chart widget, please follow the user guide.
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/chart/getting-started

**Note:** I am working for Syncfusion.